# Cannot convert object to primitive value (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```js
const idmsgeditar = conection.query(`SELEC idmensagem FROM pontos WHERE iddiscord = ${message.member.id}`)
const msgeditar = message.channel.messages.fetch(idmsgeditar)
```

I'm getting this error:

`Cannot convert object to primitive value`

Comment: You probably meant to use `SELECT` instead of `SELEC`

Comment: it keeps the same error